# Wordpress data persistence and increment in checkout bill with Snippets plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, persistence

This is about a Woocommerce, from scratch, delivery website. I also use Neve theme and Elementor.
When I clic on a product of my cart page I make appear a modal in which the user can enter additional infos.
I would like that the inputted data from the modal still persist after the page get refreshed and save that data to the order after checkout.

I tried AJAX and localstorage but obviously did it wrong. The following code is how I generate the modal with its form, when user clic on a product of the list. Additionnal data is added via an extra div with jQuery. I know it's far from state of the art, but that's what I have:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Assurez-vous que jQuery est chargé
    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            
            // Attendre que la page soit entièrement chargée
            jQuery(".woocommerce table.shop_table.cart tr").on("click", function(e) {
                // Empêcher tout comportement par défaut (par exemple, un lien)
                e.preventDefault();

                // Afficher la modale avec les champs d'entrée
                showWelcomeModalWithInputs(this);
            });

            // Empêcher la propagation du clic à l'intérieur de la modale
            jQuery(".woocommerce table.shop_table.cart tr").on("click", ".welcome-modal input, .welcome-modal button, .welcome-modal label", function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            // Fermer la modale lors du clic sur la croix de fermeture
            jQuery(".woocommerce table.shop_table.cart tr").on("click", ".welcome-modal .close, .welcome-modal .close-modal", function() {
                closeWelcomeModal();
            });

            // Fermer la modale lors du clic sur le bouton "Soumettre"
            jQuery(".woocommerce table.shop_table.cart tr").on("click", ".welcome-modal button", function() {
                submitWelcomeForm();
            });
            
        });
    }
    
    // Fonction pour remplir les champs de la modale avec les valeurs existantes
        function fillModalInputs(clickedRow) {
            // Récupérer les valeurs existantes à partir des divs ajoutées précédemment
            var infoDiv = clickedRow.find('.info-container');

            // Remplir les champs de la modale avec les valeurs existantes
            jQuery('#input1').val(infoDiv.find('p:eq(0)').text());
            jQuery('#input2').val(infoDiv.find('p:eq(1)').text());
            jQuery('#datepicker').val(infoDiv.find('p:eq(2)').text());
        }
    
    // Fonction pour fermer la modale de bienvenue
            function closeWelcomeModal() {
                // Supprimer la modale en dehors de l'élément cliqué
                jQuery('.welcome-modal').remove();

                // Supprimer la classe "active" de tous les éléments
                jQuery(".woocommerce table.shop_table.cart tr").removeClass("active");
            }
    
    // Attacher l'événement de fermeture en cliquant en dehors de la modale au document
            jQuery(document).on("click", closeWelcomeModalOutsideClick);
    
    
    
    
    
    // Fonction pour afficher la modale de bienvenue avec les champs d'entrée et le calendrier
        function showWelcomeModalWithInputs(clickedRow) {
            
            var input1Value = jQuery(clickedRow).find('.info-container p:eq(0)').text();
            var input2Value = jQuery(clickedRow).find('.info-container p:eq(1)').text();
            var datepickerValue = jQuery(clickedRow).find('.info-container p:eq(2)').text();

            var modal = jQuery('<div class="welcome-modal">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                    '<span class="close">&times;</span>' +
                    '<div class="column">' +
                        '<p><label for="input1">Numéro de colis:</label><br><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" value="' + input1Value + '"></p>' +
                        '<p><label for="input2">Adresse du relais colis:</label><br><input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" value="' + input2Value + '"></p>' +
                        '<p><label for="datepicker">Sélectionner une date:</label><br><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="' + datepickerValue + '"></p>' +
                        '<button class="submitModal">Soumettre</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>');

            // Ajout de la classe "active" pour cibler spécifiquement le conteneur cliqué
            jQuery(clickedRow).addClass("active");

            // Ajout de la modale à l'élément cliqué
            jQuery(clickedRow).append(modal);

            // Activer le Datepicker sur le champ d'entrée avec l'ID "datepicker"
            jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker();
            
            // Remplir les champs de la modale avec les valeurs existantes
                $('#input1').val(input1Value);
                $('#input2').val(input2Value);
                $('#datepicker').val(datepickerValue);
        }
    

    // Fonction pour fermer la modale de bienvenue
        function closeWelcomeModal() {
            // Supprimer la modale en dehors de l'élément cliqué
            jQuery('.welcome-modal').remove();

            // Supprimer la classe "active" de tous les éléments
            jQuery(".woocommerce table.shop_table.cart tr").removeClass("active");
        }

//      // Attacher l'événement de fermeture au document avec délégation d'événement
//      jQuery(document).on("click", ".welcome-modal .close, .welcome-modal .close-modal", function() {
//          closeWelcomeModal();
//      });
    

    // Attacher l'événement de fermeture en cliquant en dehors de la modale au document
    jQuery(document).on("click", closeWelcomeModalOutsideClick);



    // Fonction pour soumettre le formulaire dans la modale et mettre à jour les informations existantes
        function submitWelcomeForm() {
            // Récupérer le conteneur actif (celui qui a été cliqué)
            var clickedRow = jQuery(".woocommerce table.shop_table.cart tr.active");
            
            // Récupérer les valeurs des champs
                var input1Value = jQuery('#input1').val();
                var input2Value = jQuery('#input2').val();
                var datepickerValue = jQuery('#datepicker').val();


            // Vérifier si les champs contiennent une valeur avant de mettre à jour les informations existantes
            if (input1Value || input2Value || datepickerValue) {
                // Vérifier s'il existe déjà une div d'informations
                var infoDiv = clickedRow.find('.info-container');

                if (infoDiv.length > 0) {
                    // Mettre à jour les valeurs existantes dans la div d'informations
                    infoDiv.find('p:eq(0)').text(input1Value);
                    infoDiv.find('p:eq(1)').text(input2Value);
                    infoDiv.find('p:eq(2)').text(datepickerValue);
                } else {
                    // Créer une nouvelle div pour afficher les informations en bas du conteneur
                    infoDiv = jQuery('<div class="info-container same-style-as-existing-content"></div>');

                    // Ajouter les balises <p> avec les valeurs des inputs à la nouvelle div
                    infoDiv.append('<p>' + input1Value + '</p>');
                    infoDiv.append('<p>' + input2Value + '</p>');
                    infoDiv.append('<p>' + datepickerValue + '</p>');

                    // Ajouter la nouvelle div à la fin du conteneur existant
                    clickedRow.append(infoDiv);
                }
                
            }
            

    // Fermer la modale après la soumission
    closeWelcomeModal();

}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see in your code where you've attempted to store the values.  I would just use cookies, but local storage is good too.  If you store the values in cookies, they will persist   on refresh and into checkout (assuming you don't switch to another domain when for checkout - if you do, you'll need to take another approach, which I can advise you on).  Take this in small steps.  First, write code (or get a library) that gets and sets cookies and confirm it works.  Next, verify that when the form is submitted you can access the values in the form.  and so on.